# Webcam Error On Skype Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, skype, webcam

I'm trying to use my webcam with Skype. I'm using Ubuntu 11.04. I have **read other all similar questions** but they have not solved my problem.

I can use my webcam with other applications (for example : *cheese*)

I'm choosing my USB camera on Video Device Settings Page, and then clicking **test** button but I just get a black screen.

My another application using my webcam I'm not sure, can you give me an **immediately** advice?

Thank you!

ADDITIONAL: Can use advice on another application for video calls, for using instead of Skype, temporarly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run a prestarter called `skype-cam-fix`.  This tells Skype to use `videolib 4` and will then automatically start Skype.

> `cd ~
>
>   echo "#! /bin/sh" > skype-cam-fix
>
>   echo "LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype" >> skype-cam-fix
>
>   chmod a+x skype-cam-fix
>
>   sudo mv skype-cam-fix /usr/local/bin`

Then just run `skype-cam-fix` from the command line

Comment: Thank you Norm but i'm a Linux Noob. Should i run this code on terminal ? CAn you explain me step by step ?